# Remove non repeatable stochastic noise from an image

Tags: stochastic-processes, image-processing, noise, filter

Assume that you have these coordinates inside an image. The algorithm for creating these crosses comes from FAST-algorithm for corner detection.

But the problem with FAST-algorithm is that some of these crosses are not fixed. Some of the are blinking and some of them appers in different location.

I need to use a filter that can remove them. The coordinates is just two vectors of `x` and `y`.

Does anyone know a good filter for removing non repeatable stochastic noise?

[image]